# Shared Library can not be opened even though it exists: file not found

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I am trying to test an ODBC driver which was delivered to me as a shared library. I've placed the shared library into /usr/local/lib and added an entry for it in /etc/odbcinst.ini as well as a connection entry (DSN) into /etc/odbc.ini

When trying to use the `isql` command to test this connection I get the following

```
isql -v test
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/splcODBC.so' : file not found
```

Interestingly enough, when I do an `strace -o t isql -v test` I see the following info in the trace file:

```
open("/usr/local/lib/splcODBC.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \262R\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=15473838, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 13298832, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fe2065a9000
mprotect(0x7fe206fcd000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fe2071cc000, 442368, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xa23000) = 0x7fe2071cc000
mmap(0x7fe207238000, 130192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe207238000
close(3)
```

which seems to suggest that the file *is* found and successfully opened.

File information is as follows:

`ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0xa37555c3810ff5e5c78083139a3ca0232793a2e3, not stripped`

Does anybody have any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: you need to look at the rest of the strace, up until the point when the error message comes out, or when it's clear that the error message is going to go out.

Comment: One of three things: the library is not accessible; the library is not executable; or its the wrong architecture (32-bit vs 64-bit). It looks like you are *not* getting an access denied, so its not (1). Check for (2) and (3).

Comment: (1) No, it's accessible, permissions are OK; (2) How can I check this? (3) I added the file info above, looks OK (64-bit ELF)

Comment: Why no 'lib' prefix?  ( splcODBC.so vs libsplcODBC.so ).

Comment: Check if all dependencies of the library exist (use ldd).

Comment: The "ldd" tip provided by n.m. proved to be the winning answer. ldd allowed me to see that 2 libraries were unresolved; installing the appropriate versions of these libraries resolves the issue. THANKS.